# Converting chars in 2D list to int values python

Tags: python, list, matrix, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert this maze:

```
[['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'],
 ['#', 'o', '#', ' ', '#', '#'],
 ['#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', '#'],
 ['#', ' ', ' ', 'x', '#', '#'],
 ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']]
```

to this:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Is there a quick way to do convert the **char** values to **ints**? I don't know exactly what I need to be searching for. Also, what is the best way to traverse this?

Comment: What is your conversion logic? Please spell it out and add to your question. (Use [Edit]).

Comment: `[[int(x != '#') for x in i] for i in maze]` assuming *maze* is your list of lists

Answer (score 2):

```py
matrix = [['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'],
 ['#', 'o', '#', ' ', '#', '#'],
 ['#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', '#'],
 ['#', ' ', ' ', 'x', '#', '#'],
 ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']]
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    matrix[i] = list(map(lambda x: int(x != '#'), matrix[i]))
print(matrix)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t = [['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'],
 ['#', 'o', '#', ' ', '#', '#'],
 ['#', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', '#'],
 ['#', ' ', ' ', 'x', '#', '#'],
 ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']]
```

In 1 line

```
x = [[1 if a != "#" else 0 for a in p] for p in t]
```

Result

```
print(DataFrame(x))
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  0  0  0  0  0  0
1  0  1  0  1  0  0
2  0  1  0  1  0  0
3  0  1  1  1  0  0
4  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple one liner:

```
x = [[int(i != '#') for i in row] for row in Matrix]
```

`i != '#'` checks if `i` is `#` or not and returns True or False. Then True and False are converted to 1 and 0 respectively.